# Flyback transformer parameters - Inductance

Tags: power, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, high-voltage, inductance

I am designing a power supply (flyback SMPS) with universal input (120 - 240 VAC) and 6 V @15 A output (90 W). For this purpose, I have shortlisted the pwm switcher NCP1219 - selected because it doesn't need an aux coil from the transformer.

I am aware of some of the criteria of selecting a transformer for the flyback supply - switching frequency of the PWM switcher and the operating frequency of the transformer must match, the transformers power rating should be 90 W (or a little higher) and the peak current encountered on the primary side should be less than the transformers rated saturated current. I am unable to understand however how to select the right inductance for my application. Kindly provide some guidance in this scenario. If I'm missing some details or you have some criticism or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate your comments.

Comment: There's an app note for the ncp1219, [AND8393](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/and8393-d.pdf) that might be useful for you to read.

Comment: _”selected because it doesn't need an aux coil from the transformer”_ That’s a really strange selection criteria. My advice would be to read up and simulate flyback converters. Once you get over the initial crest, adding an aux winding becomes trivial.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The best info is already published online by onsemi, TI, and others.

I can think of a few fundamentals before I share one **onsemi** 20-page , how-to select a transformer.

1. Avoid Continuous Mode (CM) even with a brief short circuit by calc's to avoid instability
2. E*fs=Pmax is the maximum power and E = 1/2 LI^2 for the flyback
3. Vin min/ Vout = turns ratio with minor adjustments when fabrication is difficult
4. Energy is stored in the air gap and techniques to minimize gap leakage noise flux exist.

20 page design  [guide](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/and8393-d.pdf) for Flyback transformers.
[image]

Appreciate the exquisite regulation features of this fine chip as without you would expect to see many times the rated power in overshoot starting up or in combination with step load toggling, followed by saturation and core thermal runaway.

### Final comment

Consider a thermistor epoxied on the transformer on your experimental design for variable fan-cooling control.